# Element bigger than Page's width

Tags: html, css

I work on my Homepage on a custom Theme (WP). As I was making the page more responsive, it somehow messed up everything and I don't know what to be fair.

The Page is now somehow bigger than the window which results in a x-overflow and a scroll-bar which is contains nothing. It's kinda hard to explain, so here's a screenshot and the live view:

http://prefixaut.net

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

In your style.css Line Number **268,285,289** has Issue.

Below css to Slove these issue.

**Change these CSS:**

```
#selection .select .select-bg {
    /*left: -50px; Remove this line and Add Below lines  */
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#selection .select .select-bg-container {
    left:50% /*Remove This*/
}
#selection .select .select-icon {
    position: absolute;/*Remove This*/
}
#selection .select .select-icon i {
    /* left: -25px;  Remove this line and Add Below lines  */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting overflow-x:hidden in css. it'll work

Comment: I know that, but I was rather thinking about a solution to prevent the entire thing to be too big and mess it up instead of making it invisible to the viewer. I can do that if there's no solution is found ofc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply below given css rule to achieve your results back.

```
header {
max-width: 100% !important; 
overflow: hidden;
}
```

It will make your website look nice and your scroll will be disappearing.